# Get id of category from drop down menu

Tags: categories, get-posts, dropdown

Im trying to get the category ID from `wp_dropdown_categories();`and then pass the ID into a loop to have it output posts titles from that particular category.

I currently have this:

```
   <form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">
        <?php wp_dropdown_categories(); ?>
    </form>
        <div class="cat-list">
                <ul>
                <?php 
                global $post;
                $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'category' => $_GET['value']);
                $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : 
                  setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                <?php endforeach;
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                </ul>

        </div>
```

But it's not grabbing the category ID from the `$_GET['value']` and I'm not sure what I need to do to get it to pass that ID to the array.

Eventually, I'd like to have it so that when you select a different category that it will show the posts associated with that selected category.
But I figured that I'd try to get the select to work first and then move on from there.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with using a `form`, the only thing you're missing, you have to submit what you have selected. For example like this:

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <div>
        <?php
            $select = wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select category&orderby=name&echo=0');
            $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select);
            echo $select;
        ?>
        <noscript>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="View" />
            </div>
        </noscript>
    </div>
</form>
```

Code adapted from the [example section of the **wp_dropdown_categories()** codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories#Dropdown_without_a_Submit_Button_using_JavaScript_.282.29), there are other examples, take a look. I changed one thing, the form action is empty, because we want to stay on the page.
The variable you want would be `$_GET['cat']`; additionally you can visually see that by looking to the browser address bar, there is now something like this `?cat=1`, a query string, after you selected a category. If you don't want the query string to show, you actually can change the form method to `POST` and the variable to `$_POST['cat']`.

---

**Edit:**

On the home page this will redirect to the category archive, because wordpress reacts to the query string `cat`. In this case you have to add the `name` parameter to `wp_dropdown_categories()` and choose a unique name, in above example like this:

```
wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select category&orderby=name&echo=0&name=uniquename');
```

which leads to the variable name being `$_GET['uniquename']` or `$_POST['uniquename']`.

---

**2nd Edit:**

On first page load there is no $_GET['uniquename'] variable set, so your get_posts query will, will operate with an empty value, which leads to all post been shown. To prevent this setup a variable like shown below and use it in your arguments array.

```
$gp_cat = (isset($_GET['uniquename']) ? $_GET['uniquename'] : '5');
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'category' => $gp_cat);
```

Comment: I did see that example from the codex, but that's not what I'm trying to accomplish with this. I'm basically trying to use `wp_dropdown_categories()` to show the posts associated with the selected category. And then when another category is selected from the drop down menu, it will change to show the posts from that category. The example from the codex works if I want to re-direct to the archive page, but I'm trying to get it to load the posts within the `div`.

Comment: That's actually what this achieves. I changed the code a bit, the action is empty. I gave it a quick test with the rest of your code, it's working fine. @ultraloveninja

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. When I click on a category in the drop down select menu it re-directs me to the category archive page.

Comment: I know that in the HTML output is does give the value of each category as the ID:
`<option class="level-0" value="1">General News</option>
 <option class="level-0" value="5" selected="selected">Other Category</option>`

So, I'm not sure if there is a way to pull those values in or not.

Comment: Hmm, well either way it's not filtering out the results when a particular category is selected as default `wp_dropdown_categories('selected=5&echo=0');`. It's still showing all of the posts and not just the one post that is associated with the category id of 5.

Comment: But if you manually select a category it's working? @ultraloveninja

Comment: Yeah, if I change category => 5 it works . I'll try your method tomorrow when I'm in front of the code again. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sweet! Your 2nd edit worked! Now if I can only get to not have redirect to the archive page and have it only load the post titles when the other category is selected, I should have this in the bag.

Comment: If it's still redirecting you did something "wrong" or at least didn't read thoroughly :) I'm certain this is a correct setup. Loading post titles worked yesterday for me, with your code, without any problems. Tick the questions as solved, if we're done here. @ultraloveninja

Answer (score 0):

The `$_GET['value']` is related to the `NAME` attribute from your `SELECT`. The select name can be changed using the `name parameter` in the [`wp_dropdown_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) function too. Use `print_r($_GET);` to see what values your form is submitting and then use them in your `get_posts()` query.

Comment: Hmm, when I do a `print_r($_GET);` it returns an array with values from the URL. So, yeah. Maybe I'm going about this all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can print your id  echo $termss->term_id in drop down

```
    $terms = get_terms( 'category', array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'order_by' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'number' => 0,
    'taxonomy' => 'category'
) );

     //print_r($terms);

     foreach($terms as  $termss)
    {
    //echo "<br/>";
     //echo $termss->term_id;
        //echo "<br/>";
        ?>
    <h1> echo $termss->term_id</h1>
     <?php 
        //echo "<br/>";
      //echo $termss->slug;
      }
```