# Allow user to select categories that will display in post loop

Tags: categories, theme-development, loop

I am building a simple theme from scratch (really just for fun, and for the purpose of learning about WordPress development) but I have an idea I want to implement.

I have built a page template that will display a loop of posts from a certain category, however I want the user to be able to select the categories they want to display in that loop, preferably when they create the page and select the template.

How best to develop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`wp_dropdown_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) to do so, I've addressed this before, [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/125948/22534) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/125291/22534).